# Unable to retrieve info from API using (win_)uri module without providing credentials

Tags: windows, iis, ansible

## The Situation

I have a playbook to configure a Windows Server. That playbook is executed from a RHEL server with Ansible. The RHEL server has all required kerberos configuration and Ansible is configured to use winrm over HTTP using kerberos authentication for windows hosts. All of this works fine, I only `kinit` once and everything works.

For one of the tasks in a playbook I need to first retrieve some information from a REST API. The REST API is hosted on a Windows server using IIS and has Windows Authentication.

## The Question

I would like to use either the `win_uri` or the `uri` module to retrieve the information from the REST API, but I don't want to provide credentials. It works using the `(win_)shell` modules, why doesn’t it work for the `(win_)uri` modules?

## The Playbook

```
--- 
- name: API Test 
  vars_files: 
    - secret.yml 
  vars: 
    api_url: http://iiswebserver.my.domain/api/item/0 
  hosts: 
    - windowshost.my.domain 
  gather_facts: no 
  #debugger: on_failed 

  tasks: 

    - name: Win Shell 
      win_shell: | 
        Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri {{ api_url }} -UseDefaultCredentials 
      register: win_shell_get 

    - name: Local Shell 
      shell: | 
        curl --negotiate -u : {{ api_url }} 
      register: shell_get 
      delegate_to: localhost 

    - name: Get API info remote 
      win_uri: 
        url: "{{ api_url }}" 
        method: GET 
        return_content: yes 
        user: "{{ secret_user }}" 
        password: "{{ secret_password }}" 
      #delegate_to: localhost 
      register: api_get 

    - name: Get API info local 
      uri: 
        url: "{{ api_url }}" 
        method: GET 
        return_content: yes 
        #user: "{{ secret_user }}" 
        #password: "{{ secret_password }}" 
        #other: --negotiate 
      delegate_to: localhost 
      register: api_get_local
```

### What works

Both shell tasks work fine without entering credentials.

### What doesn't work

Using the `win_uri` module only works when I pass credentials which I don't want.
The win_uri module is executed under the system context on the target host and since the shell command works I assume the `win_uri` module should work as well.

Using the `uri` module on the localhost doesn't work. I tried several combinations of parameters (those are the commented lines), but I can't seem to get it to work.

## The Output

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with `validate_certs` option to no or `force_basic_auth` to yes?

Answer (score -2):

According to your output your iis is set to use ntlm aka windows authentication without kerberos, the reason it work on the server without ansible is because you do authenticate.
change the iis setting to anonymous